# Java TCP/IP: Finding the IP address of an incoming connection while listening on a socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip

I have a Java server implementation which listens for incoming TCP/IP connections on a specified port. Is there any way of finding the IP address of incoming/accepted connections?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, upon accepting the incoming connection you would get a Socket instance, so you can get the address to which it is connected as follows:

```
String hostAddress = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```